# 757 unexpected token error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

There is the following code:

```
source = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=sometoken'
response = JSON.parse(source)
render json:response
```

This url returns correct JSON, but I've got the exception: "757: unexpected token in 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=sometoken'". I don't understand why it appears. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not parsing the URL's content, but the url itself.
You have to fetch the content of that URL before trying to parse it.
Also leave a space after `render json:`

Try this:

```
source = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=sometoken'
response = JSON.parse(open(source).read)
render json: response
```

If that fails you might have to use URI.escape:

```
source = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=sometoken'
response = JSON.parse(open(URI.escape(source)).read)
render json: response
```

Comment: Another Solution: JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=sometoken')))